# Python BS4 Beautiful Soup HTML.Parser not working on a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have python 3.7 code to try and extract soccer stats from the following website (https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany-Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim). It seems the HTML parser I'm using with BS4 Beautiful soup is not extracting any of the tags within the website at all.

I first tried to extract particular tags, like the two different div tags representing the home and away team and tags containing player names. When that rendered an empty list of extracted tags, I simply tried to extract all div tags on that website and still I got an empty list.

Here is the code I used:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany- 
Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim'

response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
containers_home_offensive = html_soup.find_all('div')
```

Comment: The site most likely uses JavaScript to load the stats using AJAX, it's not in the HTML source.

Comment: You should call the same API that the web page uses, instead of trying to scrape HTML. You only need to scrape when there's no API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Selenium when you can just extract the match stats right off the HTML:

```py
import re
from ast import literal_eval

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany-Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim'
res = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
    }
)
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text
```

so far nothing special.

```py
match_data = re.search('var matchStats = ([^;]+)', html, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)
match_data_clean = re.sub(',,', ",'',", match_data_clean)

stats = literal_eval(match_data_clean)
```

when we inspect `match_data` we can see a bunch of arrays with invalid syntax, like this:

```
ams',,'yellow',,,21,328
```

so we clean that off with a bit of `re` magic by inserting empty strings between commas.

Printing `stats` gives us:

```
[[[37,
   1211,
   'Bayern Munich',
   'Hoffenheim',
   '24/08/2018 19:30:00',
   '24/08/2018 00:00:00',
   6,
   'FT',
   '1 : 0',
   '3 : 1',
   '',
   '',
   '3 : 1',
   'Germany',
   'Germany'],
  [[[21, [], [['Kasim Adams', '', 'yellow', '', '', 21, 328428, 0]], 0, 1],
    [23,
     [['Thomas Müller',
       'Joshua Kimmich',
       'goal',
       '(1-0)',
       '',
       23,
       37099,
       283323]],
     [],
     1,
     0],
```

from here on, it's just finding the right indices that correspond to the data you're looking for.

Comment: I just noticed a few minutes ago, for some reason even though the code you suggested is working, I am not able to scrape all the states under all 4 list items/columns ("Summary", "Offensive", "Passing", "Defensive"). I tried copying and pasting the href link to those columns as the URL link, but I still keep scraping the same data ("Summary" only). I also printed and searched through the variable html, but could not find the particular data under the three other columns. Any idea how I may be able to access those?

Answer (score 0):

Request is not the best tool to parse data in this case because this website uses JavaScript, so it is better to use Selenium and a web driver.
I gave it a try and I could parse the names of the players of both teams in 2 different lists.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

# Open web page
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='YOUR PATH') #You have to put the path of your WebDriver
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany-Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim')

# Accept
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
time.sleep(3)

# Scrolling down the page
results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#statistics-table-home-summary > table:nth-child(1)")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results)
time.sleep(7)

# Make soup
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

table_home = soup.find_all('table', {"id": "top-player-stats-summary-grid"})[0]
players_home = [a.text for a in table_home.find_all('a')]
print(players_home)

table_away = soup.find_all('table', {"id": "top-player-stats-summary-grid"})[1]
players_away = [a.text for a in table_away.find_all('a')]
print(players_away)

driver.quit()
```